# add method to ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am reading rails guides. There is an example that I don't understand. What is the functionality of this example?

> You can even create your own validation helpers and reuse them in
>   several different models. For example, an application that manages
>   surveys may find it useful to express that a certain field corresponds
>   to a set of choices:
>
> ```
> ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
>   def self.validates_as_choice(attr_name, n, options={})
>     validates attr_name, :inclusion => { { :in => 1..n }.merge!(options) }
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> Simply reopen ActiveRecord::Base and define a class method like that.
>   You’d typically put this code somewhere in config/initializers. You
>   can usethis helper like this
>
> ```
> class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
>   validates_as_choice :rating, 5
> end
> ```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Comment: I am reading these guides. I don't understand this example. Rails guides shows examples which are not very specific

Comment: ok. This worked perfect. But what if I want to show an error